# In TSQL can I create a UDF which has as input a table's row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm looking to create what I would think is simple.

I want a user defined function which takes a row from a table as imput and returns a scalar value.

Something like

```
select 
    mt.Id,
    MyUDF(mt)
from M
    MyTable mt
where mt.Price > 0
```

I understand that I can pass in the Id to the UDF, and then lookup the values from within the UDF, but that seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: Sounds like JOIN criteria.  Depending on what you intend on doing in the UDF, it's possible you don't need the UDF at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As marc_s said, the idea of sending a "row" as an object in T-SQL isn't present. You can send the data from the row as individual values, but not the row itself.

A [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) on the table itself would probably make more sense. If the value is directly dependent on the values present in the row (and *not* dependent on any external values), then this would be a solution.

For example, say I have this table:

```
Customer:
    CustomerID
    FirstName
    LastName
    ...
```

If I wanted a computed column for `FullName`, my table declaration would look like:

```
create table Customer
(
    CustomerID int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    FirstName varchar(100),
    LastName varchar(100),
    FullName as LastName + ', ' + FirstName
)
```

I could also add it after the fact with an `ALTER` statement

```
alter table Customer add FullName as LastName + ', ' + FirstName
```

Comment: very nice - this looks like the best approach for what I need

Comment: It'd be better to use a view to get a computed column - that's going to cause problems when someone writes an insert/update statement, not knowing what the full name column is.

Comment: A view is obviously an answer as well, but I would disagree that the computed column would cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

No, a RDBMS has no concept of a row as a whole - only a tuple of fields. You need to either send the individual fields separately, or send an ID which can be used inside the UDF to retrieve the fields necessary from that row.